# How to find certain text within a php variable and then replace all text between characters either side

Tags: php, string

I have a variable within PHP coming from a form that contains email addresses all separated by a comma (')
For example:
user@domain1.com,user@domain2.com,user3@domain2.com,user2@domain4.com

What I am trying to achieve is to look at the variable, find for example @domain2.com and remove everything between the comma that are either side of that email.

I know I can use str_replace to replace just the text I'm after, like so:

`$emails=str_replace("@domain2.com", "", "$emailscomma");`

However, I'm more looking to remove that entire email based on the text I'm asking it to find.

So in this example I'm wanting to remove user@domain2.com and user3@domain2.com

Is this possible?

Searched any articles I could find but couldn't find something that finds something and then replaces but more than just the text it finds.

Comment: You need regular expressions. Look into [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use regular expressions, but I would suggest a bit easier way. Operating on arrays is much easier than on strings and substrings. I would convert your string to an array and then filter it.

```
$emails = "user@domain1.com,user@domain2.com,user3@domain2.com,user2@domain4.com";

// Convert to array (by comma separator)
$emailsArray = explode(',', $emails);

$filteredArray = array_filter($emailsArray, function($email) {
    // filters out all emails with '@domain2.com' substring
    return strpos($email, '@domain2.com') === false;
});

print_r($filteredArray);
```

Now you can convert the filtered array to string again. Just use `implode()` function.